# Does inorder in reverse also classify as inorder?

Tags: binary-tree, traversal

I know inorder traversal works like this:

1. Traverse the left subtree.
2. Visit the root.
3. Traverse the right subtree.

But what if we have an algorithm that does the following

1. Traverse the right subtree.
2. Visit the root.
3. Traverse the left subtree.

Would such a tree traversal be consdered inorder as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will still be an inorder traversal. Inorder is simetrical.

From wikipedia:

> To traverse a non-empty binary tree in
>   inorder **(symmetric)**, perform the
>   following operations recursively at
>   each node:
>
> 1. Traverse the left subtree.
> 2. Visit the root.
> 3. Traverse the right subtree.

[Reference.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing for some time.

I would say, it can be called inorder traversal also. The result would be reverse sorted array instead of the sorting that would come up with left-root-right.

But the definitions are strict on saying left-root-right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming it's a binary search tree, it's still an inorder traversal. The order would be the reverse of that obtained from visiting the left subtree first, instead of the right.